I received an error while running my flutter app (The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.)
I received this long error while running my Flutter application
Launching lib\main.dart on CPH2251 in debug mode...
The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.
Build request sent: Build{id=63628fcd-df07-4268-8d5d-960fcb290585, currentDir=D:\flutter_projects\ZeroToMastery\flutter_2\android}
Attempting to read last messages from the daemon log...
Daemon pid: 8552
  log file: C:\Users\Dell\.gradle\daemon\7.6.3\daemon-8552.out.log
----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-8552.out.log -----
2024-06-07T16:09:26.792+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 20: received class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build
2024-06-07T16:09:26.793+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection] thread 20: Received non-IO message from client: Build{id=63628fcd-df07-4268-8d5d-960fcb290585, currentDir=D:\flutter_projects\ZeroToMastery\flutter_2\android}
2024-06-07T16:09:26.793+0800 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler] Received command: Build{id=63628fcd-df07-4268-8d5d-960fcb290585, currentDir=D:\flutter_projects\ZeroToMastery\flutter_2\android}.
2024-06-07T16:09:26.793+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler] Starting executing command: Build{id=63628fcd-df07-4268-8d5d-960fcb290585, currentDir=D:\flutter_projects\ZeroToMastery\flutter_2\android} with connection: socket connection from /127.0.0.1:57067 to /127.0.0.1:57068.
2024-06-07T16:09:26.799+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Command execution: started DaemonCommandExecution[command = Build{id=63628fcd-df07-4268-8d5d-960fcb290585, currentDir=D:\flutter_projects\ZeroToMastery\flutter_2\android}, connection = DefaultDaemonConnection: socket connection from /127.0.0.1:57067 to /127.0.0.1:57068] after 0.0 minutes of idle
2024-06-07T16:09:26.799+0800 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Marking the daemon as busy, address: [6b55c611-7def-4694-a1e3-f3bab10165aa port:57067, addresses:[localhost/127.0.0.1]]
2024-06-07T16:09:26.799+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Marking busy by address: [6b55c611-7def-4694-a1e3-f3bab10165aa port:57067, addresses:[localhost/127.0.0.1]]
2024-06-07T16:09:26.801+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-06-07T16:09:26.802+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-06-07T16:09:26.805+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-06-07T16:09:26.806+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] resetting idle timer
2024-06-07T16:09:26.807+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is running. Sleeping until state changes.
2024-06-07T16:09:26.808+0800 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy] Daemon is about to start building Build{id=63628fcd-df07-4268-8d5d-960fcb290585, currentDir=D:\flutter_projects\ZeroToMastery\flutter_2\android}. Dispatching build started information...
2024-06-07T16:09:26.809+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 22: dispatching org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted@55900652
2024-06-07T16:09:26.813+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment] Configuring env variables: [PATH, USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE, FLUTTER_HOST, PROCESSOR_LEVEL, SYSTEMDRIVE, SESSIONNAME, ALLUSERSPROFILE, INTEL_DEV_REDIST, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE, PUB_ENVIRONMENT, MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH, FLUTTER_TEMP_DIR, __COMPAT_LAYER, DRIVERDATA, VSCODE_PID, PROGRAMFILES, PSMODULEPATH, PROGRAMDATA, DIRNAME, NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED, USERNAME, CMD_LINE_ARGS, VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG, CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME, EXIT_WITH_ERRORLEVEL, FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING, ONEDRIVE, APP_HOME, MINGIT_PATH, PATHEXT, VSCODE_CRASH_REPORTER_PROCESS_TYPE, ONEDRIVECONSUMER, SNAPSHOT_PATH, SHARED_BIN, VSCODE_CODE_CACHE_PATH, WINDIR, ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP, HOMEPATH, PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER, PUBLIC, VS160COMCOMNTOOLS, CACHE_DIR, ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN, _SKIP, LOCALAPPDATA, COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86), USERDOMAIN, VSCODE_HANDLES_UNCAUGHT_ERRORS, DART_SDK_PATH, FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING, LOGONSERVER, JAVA_HOME, FLUTTER_TOOLS_DIR, PROMPT, PROGRAMFILES(X86), FLUTTER_ROOT, ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE, APPDATA, PROGRAMW6432, VSCODE_AMD_ENTRYPOINT, SYSTEMROOT, JAVA_EXE, DART, ANDROID_SDK_HOME, VSCODE_CWD, OS, ONEDRIVECOMMERCIAL, COMMONPROGRAMW6432, COMPUTERNAME, COMMONPROGRAMFILES, COMSPEC, PROCESSOR_REVISION, CLASSPATH, PYCHARM, APP_BASE_NAME, =D:, TEMP, FLUTTER_ALREADY_LOCKED, HOMEDRIVE, USERPROFILE, TMP, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, VSCODE_IPC_HOOK]
2024-06-07T16:09:26.831+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] About to start relaying all logs to the client via the connection.
2024-06-07T16:09:26.832+0800 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 8552). The daemon log file: C:\Users\Dell\.gradle\daemon\7.6.3\daemon-8552.out.log
2024-06-07T16:09:26.839+0800 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth] Starting build in new daemon [memory: 1.5 GiB]
2024-06-07T16:09:26.861+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has started executing the build.
2024-06-07T16:09:26.862+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=f0c0c355-a497-46f1-a5ec-b6a53d1bb4ad,javaHome=D:\Android Studio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Dell\.gradle\daemon,pid=8552,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED,-Xmx1536m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=PH,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
----- End of the daemon log -----

JVM crash log found: file:///D:/flutter_projects/ZeroToMastery/flutter_2/android/hs_err_pid8552.log

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).


I tried to solve it using CoPilot, and it suggested me to Increase Gradle JVM heap size, in which I added this org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m in my gradle.properties file in my android folder. It still didn't work, and gave me the same error.
Do you guys have any idea on how I could solve and run my flutter application again?
P.S. I use windows btw.
